# Postfix not accepting external connections

Tags: iptables, postfix

I have set up a postfix server that works just fine when accessed as localhost.  However I cannot make it available from the outside.

The relevant configs are as follows:

/etc/postfix/main.cf contains (and postfix got reloaded):

```
myhostname = <myserver.with.fully.qualified.domain.name>  # not localhost
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = <myserver.with.fully.qualified.domain.name> localhost.localdomain localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

~$ sudo iptables -L --line-numbers

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
6    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
7    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:ntp state ESTABLISHED
8    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
9    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps state NEW,ESTABLISHED
10   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
```

~$ sudo netstat -tap

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN      8067/nginx
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      18536/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:smtp                  *:*                     LISTEN      5913/master
tcp        0      0 *:https                 *:*                     LISTEN      8067/nginx
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:mysql *:*                     LISTEN      29579/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imap2              [::]:*                  LISTEN      4752/couriertcpd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      18536/sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imaps              [::]:*                  LISTEN      4803/couriertcpd
```

and at the same time -- from a different server:

```
$ nmap <myIP>
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-04-28 19:44 CEST
Nmap scan report for myServer (<myIP>)
Host is up (0.018s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
143/tcp open  imap
443/tcp open  https
993/tcp open  imaps

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 11.70 seconds
```

so SMTP is apparently not open

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your provider blocks SMTP (TCP port 25)? - Maybe not the cause, but I notice your working rules match on `state NEW,ESTABLISHED`
where for smtp you're matching on `ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED`

Comment: run `postconf -n` on the server to confirm if `inet_interfaces = all` is set by postfix


run `netstat -natpe | grep 25` to see if `0.0.0.0:25` is there


That at least will ensure postfix is listening on the relevant port.
Then, explicit the port on iptables to see what happens `iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Wierd: inet_interfaces confirmed, netstat confirmed (plus works well as localhost anyways), iptables explicit added and confirmed, nmap from the other server still does not show 25 as open port... Both machines are VPS-es at reputable hosting so unlikely anybody would block any port.  What on earth can block 25 if not iptables?  To my knowledge there's no other firewall set up...

Comment: Of course it works.  It didn't work before exactly because my ISP blocked 25; smtps (on 465) works just fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that the SMTP port (TCP 25) is not blocked, either by your hosting provider or by the ISP/network operator from which you run your remote `nmap` check.